C programming weird behaviour of "\t" (newtab)
so I've come across a weird scenario.
When running this code:
#include<stdio.h>

main(){
    printf("Fahrenheit\tCelsius\n");
    printf("Celsius\tFahrenheit\n");

}

it will show
Fahrenheit      Celsius
Celsius Fahrenheit

Can somebody explain why is the \t behaving like this?
Instead of:
Celsius Fahrenheit

it should show:
Celsius      Fahrenheit


why should it print more spaces? Celsius  is exactly 8-character long which is the same length as the tab stop

\t jumps to the next tab "column" (usually 8 characters). In the 1st line "Fahrenheit" is longer than "Celsius" in the 2nd line, and so in the 1st line you reached the next "column".

The issue has nothing to do with undefined-behavior and so I removed that tag.

Leaving off the return type on a function is long outdated and I don't think even allowed in the last few C standards, btw. should be int main(void) { ... }

The issue is not exclusive to C, or to programming in general. You'll see similar behavior when you press the Tab key in any terminal window, text editor or word processor.

It is neither weird nor anything to do with C programming.  Type the same into a text editor with 8 character tab stops and the same will happen.  That is simply where the next 8 character tab stop is in each case.  You would do better to ask how to get the output you want/expect than to ask why using TAB does not.  The explanation is obvious, but does not help you and is not programming related.

The tab character isn't the equivalent of a certain number of spaces.  It advances to the next tab "stop".
In the case of your particular terminal, it appears that tab stops are every 8 characters:
t       t       t       t
-------------------------
Fahrenheit      Celsius
Celsius Fahrenheit

From the above, it should be more clear what happened.  In the first line, the tab character advanced to the next tab stop which is the 3rd, while on the second line the next tab stop is the 2nd.

It's probably worth mentioning that it's whatever program you are using to display the text that's doing this, not C. The program simply outputs a single character.

The default tab-stop in most terminals is eight columns, meaning that a tab character will appear as a space of 1-8 columns such that the next character starts at the next tab-stop (multiple of 8 columns).
If you want to align arbitrary strings, you'll have to measure them yourself and print them with an appropriate field width.
For example:
const char *sa = "Celsius";
const char *sb = "Fahrenheit";
int la = strlen(sa);
int lb = strlen(sb);
int width = (la > lb) ? la : lb;
printf("%*s %*s\n", width, sa, width, sb);
printf("%*s %*s\n", width, sb, width, sa);

Output:
   Celsius Fahrenheit
Fahrenheit    Celsius

If you want left-align, use %-*s instead of %*s, yielding
Celsius    Fahrenheit
Fahrenheit Celsius   


It's probably worth mentioning that the the tab is rendered by whatever program you are using to display the text, not C. The program simply outputs a single character.

You typically don't know which strings you want to display when you decide on output format. So it's easier to use some "magic number", like 20, hoping that all your displayed strings will be shorter.

It is not weird, nor it is even related with C or your program.

Can somebody explain why is the \t behaving like this?

It all depends on where the TAB is being processed. The behavior of TAB processing is to advance the cursor to the next tab stop, and tab stop columns are set someplace, application specific or terminal emulator specific.
Also note that TAB stops can be used at specific columns and not at specific constant column interval like 4 or 8 columns like in most editors.
If you are using windows Terminal there is a settings.json file where you can set them.
In Linux you have the tabs command, that is often installed along in Windows when you install git or gcc. Many of my Windows machines have this tabs command and reports the version --- tabs -V --- as 6.4
Under Windows the default is to have VIRTUAL TERMINAL PROCESSING on console, and in this case you can also use VT100 commands to set and reset tab stops.
EXAMPLE
This is tabs.txt content, just a grid and a sequence \t1\t2\t3\t4
         1         2         3         4         5         6
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
              1    2    3    4

and an example under windows 10
C:\Users\SO >ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.5011]

C:\Users\SO >type tabs.txt
         1         2         3         4         5         6
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
              1    2    3    4

C:\Users\SO >tabs 15 20 25 30

C:\Users\SO >type tabs.txt
         1         2         3         4         5         6
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
              1    2    3    4

C:\Users\SO >tabs -V
ncurses 6.4.20221231

C:\Users\SO >

